# Flutter : how to use list components on Flutter with stateful widget

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-web

**1. Settings**

I want to make a BMI calculator. I set my calculator to distinguish five different states of human body (high fast, fast, chubby, normal, thin). I put those states on the list. However, If I call one of those states using 'num[0]', it doesn't work properly.

**2. What I made**

[image: BMI calculator with input1(180), input2(60)]

**3. What I want to know**

Instead of facing the real 'num[0]', I want this app to embed the first data inside the list 'num'.

**4. My WHOLE code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //1. variables

  late TextEditingController input1;
  late TextEditingController input2;
  late double sum;
  late String sentence;
  var num = ['hight fast', 'fast', 'chubby', 'normal', 'thin'];

  //2. initialization
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    input1 = TextEditingController();
    input2 = TextEditingController();
    sum = 0;

    sentence = "";
  }

//3. main
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: input1,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter your height (: cm)'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: input2,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter your weight (: kg)'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 21,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.amber,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  onCheck();
                },
                child: const Text('RESULT'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text(
                  sentence,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    fontSize: 21,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  onCheck() {
    setState(() {
      sum = double.parse(input2.text) /
          (((double.parse(input1.text)) / 100) *
              ((double.parse(input1.text)) / 100));

      if (sum >= 30) {
        sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is num[0]';
      } else if (sum >= 25) {
        sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is num[0]';
      } else if (sum >= 23) {
        sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is num[0]';
      } else if (sum >= 18.5) {
        sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is num[0]';
      } else {
        sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is num[0]';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading. I appreciate all your answers, even tiny short small ideas.

Comment: If you are accessing Object or List or Map inside of String, use curly braces `{}`. E.g. `sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is ${num[0]}'`

Comment: "your BMI is $sum, your state is ${num[0]}" or "your BMI is $sum, your state is"+ num[0].toString

Answer (score 2):

You have to use num like this:

```
'Your BMI is ... ${num[0]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way

```
sentence = 'your BMI is $sum, your state is ${num[0]}'
```

Comment: Thanks to your kind answer, I was able to make my own app properly. Would you mind if i ask related question? if it is okay, please tell me the difference between $sum and ${num[0]} . I thought the previous one is int, and the next one is the String type. I guess different types made them to use different syntax ($ or $ { } ). If it is wrong, please explain. Thank you for reading :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the type. You can use $ for all primitive tyypes. The {} are needed for "complex types" like ${num[0]}, ${object.property} and so on.

Comment: The difference is so simple wen you need to call fonction or property from ( class or object  ) like your num enum or even some code. you must put it in {}. But with simple variable you don't need to.